# print("print("Hello World!")") doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to use this code `print("print("Hello World!")")` but it gives me an error.

I thought it would print on the console this:

> print("Hello World!")

but it didn't work. I think it may be a problem about brackets or `"` this but i can't figure it out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You meant to write: `print('print("Hello World!")')`. You can print the `"` character if you enclose it in single quotes.

Comment: Thanks it worked! Can you tell me what would I do if I wanted to print the code you sent me? this --> print('print("Hello World!")'

Comment: Do you mean that you want to see `print('print("Hello World!")')` on the console?

Comment: yes012345678901

Comment: More generally, you can escape the inner `"` characters, e.g. `print("print(\"Hello World!\")")`  This provides a more convenient way to mix single and double quotes in the same string.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more generic answer that demonstrates how to do things to an arbitrary depth, I would go with escaped backslash quotes.

- First.: `"`
- Second: `\"`
- Third:  `\\\"`
- fourth: `\\\\\\\"`

The key is that in addition to escaping the double quote ultimately with `\"` at each level of nesting you need to escape the prior level's backslashes.

Here are some demos:

```py
print("print(\"Hello World!\")")
print("print(\"print(\\\"Hello World!\\\")\")")
print("print(\"print(\\\"print(\\\\\\\"Hello World!\\\\\\\")\\\")\")")
exec("exec(\"exec(\\\"print(\\\\\\\"Hello World!\\\\\\\")\\\")\")")
```

That should give you:

```
print("Hello World!")
print("print(\"Hello World!\")")
print("print(\"print(\\\"Hello World!\\\")\")")
Hello World!
```

Answer (score 0):

So now you can use `triple quotes`:

```py
s = """print('print("Hello World!")')"""
print(s)
```

Output as requested

Comment: first one: "
second one: '
third one: """
fourth one: ?
nth one: ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify a depth to which the `print()`s are nested with, say, a single `"` mark, you could use this:

```py
def surround_in_print(msg, depth):
    if depth == 0:
        return msg
    return f'print("{surround_in_print(msg, depth-1)}")'

print(surround_in_print("Hello World!", 5))
```

Output:

```
print("print("print("print("print("Hello World!")")")")")
```

If you wanted to use an arbitrary sequence of quote-like marks you could use this:

```py
def surround_in_print_with_quotes(msg, quotes):
    if not quotes:
        return msg
    
    q, *rest = quotes
    return f'print({q}{surround_in_print_with_quotes(msg, rest)}{q})'

first = '"'
second = "'"
third = '"""'
fourth = "?"
print(surround_in_print_with_quotes("Hello World!", (first, second, third, fourth)))
```

Output:

```
print("print('print("""print(?Hello World!?)""")')")
```